# Image Button turns white after inserting an image

Tags: java, android, image

I am trying to add an `image button` to my `activity`, but for some reason when I add an image to the `image button` the `image button` turns into a white box.

Here is my `.xml` code for the `image button`.

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image1"/>
```

Here is an image:[ｉｍａｇｅ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4tso.png)

I have checked other stackoverflow post about this topic, but they are always dead-ends.  People asking if you have erased the background in photoshop, etc..

I am using Android Studio as an IDE also.  I have tried to find some tuts online over adding an image view to see if my code is wrong, and i've seen videos of people using the same code but using eclipse, and it will work. Not for sure if it's an IDE problem or what.

Comment: Did you tried to give fix size to the component?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. Maybe it is too late, but, as I faced the same question, I'm going to give you an answer. In my case, the problem was the resizing of the src, that was not made well. Your code is right, but I solved it with this two lines

> ```
>     android:scaleType="fitCenter"
>     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
> ```

So you only have to insert them on your code. This is:

```
<ImageButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/imageButton"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:src="@drawable/image1"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

This should center your src image on the view and give it the limits of the ImageButton. After that, you can adjust the size of the ImBtt with the layout_width and layout_height.

This worked fine for me. Even late, hope it helps.